# Web Application with Background Job That Loops Forever

Tags: .net-core, application-design, web-application-design

I am trying to design a new application but am a little stuck on the best way to do it.

What I want to be able to do is have a bot connected to an irc channel which is  gathering information from the chat messages and then I want to have an HTTP endpoint where I can get results from the information gathered so far.

I have a bot running that gathers the information I want and I can create endpoints but how do I architecture this into 1 application? Do I have 2 applications? 1 that outputs to a file and the endpoint just reads the file and outputs that? I would prefer it in 1 application but haven't been able to find a solution like this so far.

I am using DotNet core  2.0 currently and deploying to a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: That depends on your definition of 'application'. An 'application' can be a bunch of executables. Do you mean single EXE? If you take a look at 'service oriented architecture' it would suggest two services running independently. (two exe's)

Comment: I am using a WebHostBuilder within my current web app, so was hoping I could somehow integrate my irc bot into that. I'd expect I could use a reference but it would still only be one web app.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend running background jobs inside a web server. Although heaps of people do actually do it (using hangfire as already suggested), a webserver is not a job server.

Comment: So would you suggest having two applications, one doing to processing and the web app just returning an output from the one doing the processing?

Comment: That's the way I would do it. That way if one process crashes it will be isolated from the other. Troubleshooting and performance tuning individual processes is easier if you can actually see them seperately (i.e. the two gatherer and the result endpoint are not mixed up inside the same web server process). And the two processes don't need to talk directly to each other - one of them writes to a log, one of them reads from a log. You could in theory scale it up to two seperate pi's with one process running on each (and have two feeble pieces of hardware)

Comment: This woudl mean one process is deifnitely a web API running inside a web server, and the other is some kind of standalone service or console thing (whatever dotnet / pi supports)

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid, I will do it this way. I am running Docker containers so they will be completely separate and should be easier to scale this way as well.

Comment: @SamJ as an aside, imagine if your service runs into errors and throws an exception. Do you want your IRC bot to be able to bring down your website because it ran into an uncaught error?

Answer (score 0):

It depends of workload.
If app gathering information doing it periodically and do nothing rest of the time I would suggest start this as a ASP.NET service:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
    host.Run();
}
```

Install all dependencies for you current console app (this will work).
To gather data you can use **HangFire**. It library to run background jobs.
To run background job reccurence register job like this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => { //Gather data here },
    Cron.Daily);
```

Comment: Currently my console app runs in loop constantly checking for new messages to process, I would like to keep it as real time as possible. Does adding a RecurringJob keep it processing messages in real time or only when I call my endpoint?

Comment: Minimum period can be set to 1 minute. So if you need it in real time, create loop in new Task with loop. But it can be too much CPU or O/I intensive (depends how you data gathering looks).